# Adding % labels to pie chart that doesn't have Y or X defined

Tags: r, ggplot2, pie-chart

I am trying to add labels to pie chart I created. I searched web to find some information about it but I don't think anyone makes pie charts the way I do. I basically have only "fill" definied and thus I don't know how can I add labels to it in correct positions. I would like the numbers in % to be shown either on top of the correct slices of pie chart or next to it with lines leading to corresponding to them slice.
Thank you for all the help in advance!

Here is my code:

```
mypalette<-brewer.pal(10,"RdYlBu")
      
    ggplot(sprzed, aes(x=factor(1), fill=factor(Jakiej.marki.kupil.Pan...Pani.motocykl.))) +
      geom_bar(width=1, color="black") +
      scale_fill_manual("Marka motocykla",values = mypalette)+
      coord_polar("y", start=0)+
      labs(title = "Wykres liczby zakupionych motocykli danej marki", x="", y="")+
      theme(text = element_text(size=24),
            axis.title.x=element_blank(),
            axis.text.x=element_blank(),
            axis.ticks.x=element_blank(),
            axis.title.y=element_blank(),
            axis.text.y=element_blank(),
            axis.ticks.y=element_blank()
            )
```

And data:

```
structure(list(Sygnatura.czasowa = c("2020/11/29 5:05:05 PM CET", 
"2020/11/29 5:05:31 PM CET", "2020/11/29 5:05:54 PM CET", "2020/11/29 5:06:10 PM CET", 
"2020/11/29 5:06:23 PM CET", "2020/11/29 5:07:12 PM CET", "2020/11/29 5:08:00 PM CET", 
"2020/11/29 5:08:17 PM CET", "2020/11/29 5:08:21 PM CET", "2020/11/29 5:08:36 PM CET", 
"2020/11/29 5:08:51 PM CET", "2020/11/29 5:09:34 PM CET", "2020/11/29 5:10:10 PM CET", 
"2020/11/29 5:10:27 PM CET", "2020/11/29 5:10:47 PM CET", "2020/11/29 5:10:56 PM CET", 
"2020/11/29 5:11:11 PM CET", "2020/11/29 5:11:20 PM CET", "2020/11/29 5:11:50 PM CET", 
"2020/11/29 5:12:00 PM CET", "2020/11/29 5:12:18 PM CET", "2020/11/29 5:12:21 PM CET", 
"2020/11/29 5:12:53 PM CET", "2020/11/29 5:13:17 PM CET", "2020/11/29 5:13:20 PM CET", 
"2020/11/29 5:14:02 PM CET", "2020/11/29 5:14:25 PM CET", "2020/11/29 5:14:42 PM CET", 
"2020/11/29 5:14:43 PM CET", "2020/11/29 5:15:05 PM CET", "2020/11/29 5:15:07 PM CET", 
"2020/11/29 5:15:22 PM CET", "2020/11/29 5:15:37 PM CET", "2020/11/29 5:16:17 PM CET", 
"2020/11/29 5:16:33 PM CET", "2020/11/29 5:16:46 PM CET", "2020/11/29 5:16:50 PM CET", 
"2020/11/29 5:16:50 PM CET", "2020/11/29 5:17:11 PM CET", "2020/11/29 5:17:12 PM CET", 
"2020/11/29 5:17:20 PM CET", "2020/11/29 5:17:43 PM CET", "2020/11/29 5:17:57 PM CET", 
"2020/11/29 5:17:59 PM CET", "2020/11/29 5:18:35 PM CET", "2020/11/29 5:18:51 PM CET", 
"2020/11/29 5:18:53 PM CET", "2020/11/29 5:19:09 PM CET", "2020/11/29 5:19:26 PM CET", 
"2020/11/29 5:19:32 PM CET", "2020/11/29 5:19:45 PM CET", "2020/11/29 5:19:50 PM CET", 
"2020/11/29 5:19:50 PM CET", "2020/11/29 5:20:26 PM CET", "2020/11/29 5:20:36 PM CET", 
"2020/11/29 5:20:39 PM CET", "2020/11/29 5:21:07 PM CET", "2020/11/29 5:21:09 PM CET", 
"2020/11/29 5:21:30 PM CET", "2020/11/29 5:21:54 PM CET", "2020/11/29 5:22:28 PM CET", 
"2020/11/29 5:22:30 PM CET", "2020/11/29 5:22:45 PM CET", "2020/11/29 5:22:46 PM CET", 
"2020/11/29 5:22:47 PM CET", "2020/11/29 5:23:02 PM CET", "2020/11/29 5:23:22 PM CET", 
"2020/11/29 5:23:38 PM CET", "2020/11/29 5:23:40 PM CET", "2020/11/29 5:23:58 PM CET", 
"2020/11/29 5:24:14 PM CET", "2020/11/29 5:24:18 PM CET", "2020/11/29 5:24:41 PM CET", 
"2020/11/29 5:24:58 PM CET", "2020/11/29 5:25:06 PM CET", "2020/11/29 5:25:25 PM CET", 
"2020/11/29 5:25:48 PM CET", "2020/11/29 5:25:54 PM CET", "2020/11/29 5:27:21 PM CET", 
"2020/11/29 5:27:48 PM CET", "2020/11/29 5:28:20 PM CET", "2020/11/29 5:28:21 PM CET", 
"2020/11/29 5:29:06 PM CET", "2020/11/29 5:29:08 PM CET", "2020/11/29 5:29:57 PM CET", 
"2020/11/29 5:30:08 PM CET", "2020/11/29 5:30:29 PM CET", "2020/11/29 5:30:55 PM CET", 
"2020/11/29 5:30:56 PM CET", "2020/11/29 5:31:08 PM CET", "2020/11/29 5:31:17 PM CET", 
"2020/11/29 5:31:25 PM CET", "2020/11/29 5:31:57 PM CET", "2020/11/29 5:32:16 PM CET", 
"2020/11/29 5:32:32 PM CET", "2020/11/29 5:32:45 PM CET", "2020/11/29 5:33:01 PM CET", 
"2020/11/29 5:33:07 PM CET", "2020/11/29 5:33:35 PM CET", "2020/11/29 5:33:55 PM CET"
), W.ktorym.roku.kupil.Pan...Pani.motocykl. = c(2019L, 2019L, 
2019L, 2019L, 2019L, 2019L, 2019L, 2019L, 2020L, 2019L, 2019L, 
2020L, 2019L, 2019L, 2019L, 2020L, 2019L, 2020L, 2020L, 2019L, 
2019L, 2019L, 2020L, 2019L, 2020L, 2019L, 2020L, 2020L, 2019L, 
2019L, 2020L, 2019L, 2020L, 2020L, 2020L, 2020L, 2020L, 2020L, 
2020L, 2020L, 2019L, 2019L, 2020L, 2019L, 2020L, 2019L, 2020L, 
2020L, 2020L, 2020L, 2019L, 2020L, 2020L, 2020L, 2020L, 2019L, 
2020L, 2019L, 2020L, 2020L, 2020L, 2019L, 2019L, 2020L, 2020L, 
2020L, 2020L, 2020L, 2019L, 2020L, 2019L, 2020L, 2020L, 2019L, 
2019L, 2019L, 2020L, 2019L, 2020L, 2019L, 2019L, 2020L, 2019L, 
2020L, 2019L, 2020L, 2020L, 2019L, 2020L, 2019L, 2020L, 2019L, 
2019L, 2019L, 2019L, 2020L, 2020L, 2019L, 2020L, 2020L), Jakiej.jest.Pan...Pani.plci. = c("Kobieta", 
"Kobieta", "Kobieta", "Kobieta", "Kobieta", "Kobieta", "Kobieta", 
"Mezczyzna", "Mezczyzna", "Mezczyzna", "Mezczyzna", "Kobieta", 
"Mezczyzna", "Kobieta", "Mezczyzna", "Mezczyzna", "Mezczyzna", 
"Mezczyzna", "Mezczyzna", "Mezczyzna", "Mezczyzna", "Mezczyzna", 
"Mezczyzna", "Kobieta", "Kobieta", "Mezczyzna", "Kobieta", "Mezczyzna", 
"Mezczyzna", "Mezczyzna", "Mezczyzna", "Mezczyzna", "Mezczyzna", 
"Mezczyzna", "Mezczyzna", "Kobieta", "Mezczyzna", "Mezczyzna", 
"Kobieta", "Mezczyzna", "Mezczyzna", "Mezczyzna", "Kobieta", 
"Kobieta", "Kobieta", "Mezczyzna", "Kobieta", "Mezczyzna", "Mezczyzna", 
"Kobieta", "Kobieta", "Kobieta", "Kobieta", "Kobieta", "Mezczyzna", 
"Mezczyzna", "Mezczyzna", "Mezczyzna", "Kobieta", "Kobieta", 
"Mezczyzna", "Mezczyzna", "Mezczyzna", "Kobieta", "Kobieta", 
"Kobieta", "Mezczyzna", "Mezczyzna", "Mezczyzna", "Mezczyzna", 
"Mezczyzna", "Kobieta", "Mezczyzna", "Mezczyzna", "Mezczyzna", 
"Mezczyzna", "Mezczyzna", "Mezczyzna", "Mezczyzna", "Mezczyzna", 
"Mezczyzna", "Kobieta", "Mezczyzna", "Mezczyzna", "Mezczyzna", 
"Mezczyzna", "Kobieta", "Mezczyzna", "Mezczyzna", "Mezczyzna", 
"Mezczyzna", "Mezczyzna", "Mezczyzna", "Mezczyzna", "Mezczyzna", 
"Mezczyzna", "Mezczyzna", "Mezczyzna", "Kobieta", "Mezczyzna"
), Jaki.jest.Pana...Pani.status.spoleczny = c("Student", "Pracownik fizyczny", 
"Pracownik fizyczny", "Pracownik umyslowy", "Pracownik fizyczny", 
"Pracownik fizyczny", "Pracownik fizyczny", "Pracownik fizyczny", 
"Student", "Pracownik fizyczny", "Student", "Pracownik fizyczny", 
"Pracownik fizyczny", "Pracownik umyslowy", "Pracownik fizyczny", 
"Bezrobotny", "Bezrobotny", "Pracownik umyslowy", "Pracownik fizyczny", 
"Pracownik fizyczny", "Pracownik umyslowy", "Pracownik fizyczny", 
"Bezrobotny", "Pracownik umyslowy", "Student", "Pracownik umyslowy", 
"Bezrobotny", "Pracownik fizyczny", "Pracownik fizyczny", "Student", 
"Student", "Pracownik fizyczny", "Pracownik fizyczny", "Pracownik umyslowy", 
"Student", "Student", "Pracownik umyslowy", "Pracownik fizyczny", 
"Pracownik umyslowy", "Pracownik fizyczny", "Pracownik umyslowy", 
"Pracownik umyslowy", "Student", "Pracownik umyslowy", "Pracownik fizyczny", 
"Pracownik umyslowy", "Pracownik umyslowy", "Pracownik umyslowy", 
"Pracownik fizyczny", "Student", "Student", "Student", "Pracownik fizyczny", 
"Pracownik umyslowy", "Pracownik fizyczny", "Pracownik umyslowy", 
"Pracownik fizyczny", "Pracownik fizyczny", "Student", "Pracownik umyslowy", 
"Bezrobotny", "Pracownik fizyczny", "Pracownik umyslowy", "Student", 
"Pracownik fizyczny", "Pracownik umyslowy", "Bezrobotny", "Student", 
"Pracownik umyslowy", "Pracownik fizyczny", "Pracownik fizyczny", 
"Bezrobotny", "Student", "Pracownik umyslowy", "Pracownik fizyczny", 
"Pracownik umyslowy", "Pracownik fizyczny", "Pracownik fizyczny", 
"Pracownik fizyczny", "Pracownik fizyczny", "Pracownik fizyczny", 
"Bezrobotny", "Pracownik fizyczny", "Pracownik fizyczny", "Pracownik fizyczny", 
"Student", "Student", "Pracownik umyslowy", "Pracownik umyslowy", 
"Pracownik umyslowy", "Pracownik fizyczny", "Pracownik umyslowy", 
"Pracownik umyslowy", "Pracownik umyslowy", "Pracownik umyslowy", 
"Student", "Pracownik fizyczny", "Pracownik fizyczny", "Pracownik fizyczny", 
"Pracownik fizyczny"), Do.jakiej.grupy.wiekowej.Pan...Pani.nalezy. = c("18 - 25", 
"26 -35", "36 - 45", "46 - 55", "36 - 45", "56 - 65", "46 - 55", 
"36 - 45", "18 - 25", "46 - 55", "18 - 25", "26 -35", "26 -35", 
"26 -35", "> 65", "18 - 25", "18 - 25", "36 - 45", "18 - 25", 
"46 - 55", "56 - 65", "26 -35", "18 - 25", "56 - 65", "18 - 25", 
"46 - 55", "18 - 25", "26 -35", "26 -35", "18 - 25", "18 - 25", 
"46 - 55", "26 -35", "26 -35", "18 - 25", "18 - 25", "46 - 55", 
"26 -35", "26 -35", "26 -35", "46 - 55", "18 - 25", "18 - 25", 
"26 -35", "26 -35", "46 - 55", "18 - 25", "56 - 65", "36 - 45", 
"18 - 25", "18 - 25", "18 - 25", "36 - 45", "18 - 25", "18 - 25", 
"36 - 45", "18 - 25", "18 - 25", "18 - 25", "26 -35", "18 - 25", 
"36 - 45", "36 - 45", "18 - 25", "26 -35", "26 -35", "18 - 25", 
"18 - 25", "56 - 65", "36 - 45", "26 -35", "18 - 25", "26 -35", 
"26 -35", "26 -35", "36 - 45", "26 -35", "46 - 55", "26 -35", 
"26 -35", "26 -35", "18 - 25", "36 - 45", "36 - 45", "56 - 65", 
"18 - 25", "18 - 25", "26 -35", "36 - 45", "36 - 45", "26 -35", 
"46 - 55", "46 - 55", "46 - 55", "36 - 45", "18 - 25", "36 - 45", 
"46 - 55", "26 -35", "46 - 55"), Jaki.kupil.Pan...Pani.motocykl. = c("Uzywany", 
"Uzywany", "Uzywany", "Nowy", "Nowy", "Uzywany", "Nowy", "Nowy", 
"Uzywany", "Uzywany", "Uzywany", "Nowy", "Uzywany", "Uzywany", 
"Uzywany", "Uzywany", "Nowy", "Nowy", "Nowy", "Nowy", "Nowy", 
"Uzywany", "Uzywany", "Nowy", "Uzywany", "Uzywany", "Uzywany", 
"Uzywany", "Uzywany", "Uzywany", "Nowy", "Nowy", "Uzywany", "Uzywany", 
"Uzywany", "Uzywany", "Nowy", "Uzywany", "Uzywany", "Uzywany", 
"Uzywany", "Nowy", "Uzywany", "Nowy", "Uzywany", "Nowy", "Uzywany", 
"Uzywany", "Uzywany", "Nowy", "Nowy", "Uzywany", "Nowy", "Uzywany", 
"Uzywany", "Uzywany", "Uzywany", "Uzywany", "Uzywany", "Uzywany", 
"Uzywany", "Nowy", "Nowy", "Uzywany", "Uzywany", "Nowy", "Nowy", 
"Nowy", "Uzywany", "Uzywany", "Nowy", "Nowy", "Uzywany", "Nowy", 
"Nowy", "Uzywany", "Uzywany", "Uzywany", "Uzywany", "Uzywany", 
"Uzywany", "Nowy", "Uzywany", "Nowy", "Nowy", "Uzywany", "Uzywany", 
"Nowy", "Nowy", "Uzywany", "Uzywany", "Nowy", "Uzywany", "Nowy", 
"Nowy", "Uzywany", "Uzywany", "Nowy", "Uzywany", "Uzywany"), 
    Jakiej.marki.kupil.Pan...Pani.motocykl. = c("Honda", "Honda", 
    "Yamaha", "Kawasaki", "Honda", "Harley Davidson", "Kawasaki", 
    "Junak", "Yamaha", "Romet", "Honda", "Kawasaki", "Bmw", "Suzuki", 
    "Harley Davidson", "Honda", "Honda", "Harley Davidson", "Suzuki", 
    "Bmw", "KTM", "Yamaha", "Junak", "Suzuki", "Suzuki", "Benelli", 
    "Honda", "Yamaha", "Kawasaki", "Honda", "Kawasaki", "Kawasaki", 
    "Bmw", "Honda", "Yamaha", "Yamaha", "KTM", "KTM", "Suzuki", 
    "Yamaha", "Kawasaki", "Yamaha", "Yamaha", "Suzuki", "Yamaha", 
    "Benelli", "Yamaha", "Bmw", "Suzuki", "Romet", "Junak", "Yamaha", 
    "Suzuki", "Suzuki", "Honda", "Romet", "Yamaha", "Honda", 
    "Yamaha", "Yamaha", "Suzuki", "Benelli", "Junak", "Honda", 
    "Suzuki", "Honda", "Kawasaki", "Kawasaki", "Yamaha", "Kawasaki", 
    "Suzuki", "Suzuki", "Yamaha", "Kawasaki", "Yamaha", "Harley Davidson", 
    "Suzuki", "Honda", "Bmw", "Kawasaki", "Kawasaki", "Kawasaki", 
    "Romet", "Junak", "Yamaha", "Junak", "Yamaha", "Honda", "KTM", 
    "Kawasaki", "Romet", "Honda", "Yamaha", "Yamaha", "Honda", 
    "Honda", "Yamaha", "Yamaha", "Honda", "Honda"), Pana...Pani.motocykl.jest. = c("Sprowadzony zza granicy", 
    "Sprowadzony zza granicy", "Sprowadzony zza granicy", "Kupiony w Polsce", 
    "Kupiony w Polsce", "Kupiony w Polsce", "Kupiony w Polsce", 
    "Kupiony w Polsce", "Kupiony w Polsce", "Kupiony w Polsce", 
    "Sprowadzony zza granicy", "Kupiony w Polsce", "Kupiony w Polsce", 
    "Kupiony w Polsce", "Kupiony w Polsce", "Kupiony w Polsce", 
    "Kupiony w Polsce", "Kupiony w Polsce", "Kupiony w Polsce", 
    "Kupiony w Polsce", "Kupiony w Polsce", "Sprowadzony zza granicy", 
    "Kupiony w Polsce", "Sprowadzony zza granicy", "Kupiony w Polsce", 
    "Sprowadzony zza granicy", "Kupiony w Polsce", "Kupiony w Polsce", 
    "Sprowadzony zza granicy", "Sprowadzony zza granicy", "Kupiony w Polsce", 
    "Sprowadzony zza granicy", "Kupiony w Polsce", "Kupiony w Polsce", 
    "Kupiony w Polsce", "Kupiony w Polsce", "Kupiony w Polsce", 
    "Kupiony w Polsce", "Kupiony w Polsce", "Kupiony w Polsce", 
    "Sprowadzony zza granicy", "Kupiony w Polsce", "Kupiony w Polsce", 
    "Kupiony w Polsce", "Kupiony w Polsce", "Kupiony w Polsce", 
    "Kupiony w Polsce", "Kupiony w Polsce", "Kupiony w Polsce", 
    "Kupiony w Polsce", "Kupiony w Polsce", "Kupiony w Polsce", 
    "Kupiony w Polsce", "Kupiony w Polsce", "Kupiony w Polsce", 
    "Kupiony w Polsce", "Sprowadzony zza granicy", "Kupiony w Polsce", 
    "Kupiony w Polsce", "Kupiony w Polsce", "Kupiony w Polsce", 
    "Kupiony w Polsce", "Kupiony w Polsce", "Kupiony w Polsce", 
    "Kupiony w Polsce", "Kupiony w Polsce", "Sprowadzony zza granicy", 
    "Sprowadzony zza granicy", "Sprowadzony zza granicy", "Sprowadzony zza granicy", 
    "Sprowadzony zza granicy", "Sprowadzony zza granicy", "Sprowadzony zza granicy", 
    "Sprowadzony zza granicy", "Sprowadzony zza granicy", "Kupiony w Polsce", 
    "Sprowadzony zza granicy", "Sprowadzony zza granicy", "Sprowadzony zza granicy", 
    "Sprowadzony zza granicy", "Sprowadzony zza granicy", "Kupiony w Polsce", 
    "Sprowadzony zza granicy", "Sprowadzony zza granicy", "Kupiony w Polsce", 
    "Kupiony w Polsce", "Sprowadzony zza granicy", "Sprowadzony zza granicy", 
    "Sprowadzony zza granicy", "Sprowadzony zza granicy", "Kupiony w Polsce", 
    "Kupiony w Polsce", "Sprowadzony zza granicy", "Sprowadzony zza granicy", 
    "Sprowadzony zza granicy", "Sprowadzony zza granicy", "Sprowadzony zza granicy", 
    "Kupiony w Polsce", "Sprowadzony zza granicy", "Sprowadzony zza granicy"
    ), W.jakim.miesiacu.kupil.Pan...Pani.motocykl. = c("Styczen", 
    "Marzec", "Kwiecien", "Wrzesien", "Pazdziernik", "Lipiec", 
    "Lipiec", "Czerwiec", "Marzec", "Kwiecien", "Styczen", "Maj", 
    "Lipiec", "Wrzesien", "Listopad", "Sierpien", "Maj", "Maj", 
    "Kwiecien", "Marzec", "Czerwiec", "Listopad", "Sierpien", 
    "Wrzesien", "Kwiecien", "Grudzien", "Maj", "Czerwiec", "Czerwiec", 
    "Lipiec", "Marzec", "Sierpien", "Czerwiec", "Pazdziernik", 
    "Styczen", "Marzec", "Kwiecien", "Kwiecien", "Kwiecien", 
    "Czerwiec", "Kwiecien", "Pazdziernik", "Kwiecien", "Marzec", 
    "Kwiecien", "Marzec", "Styczen", "Maj", "Marzec", "Luty", 
    "Listopad", "Marzec", "Lipiec", "Styczen", "Wrzesien", "Maj", 
    "Sierpien", "Wrzesien", "Styczen", "Luty", "Czerwiec", "Czerwiec", 
    "Marzec", "Maj", "Marzec", "Kwiecien", "Lipiec", "Czerwiec", 
    "Pazdziernik", "Marzec", "Czerwiec", "Styczen", "Pazdziernik", 
    "Pazdziernik", "Maj", "Styczen", "Grudzien", "Kwiecien", 
    "Luty", "Marzec", "Czerwiec", "Czerwiec", "Kwiecien", "Luty", 
    "Kwiecien", "Lipiec", "Maj", "Wrzesien", "Czerwiec", "Kwiecien", 
    "Czerwiec", "Styczen", "Kwiecien", "Kwiecien", "Wrzesien", 
    "Luty", "Marzec", "Kwiecien", "Czerwiec", "Styczen")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-100L))
```